# confused with Ruby accessor methods

Tags: ruby, class, syntax, accessor

i'm really confused how to name method names in Ruby classes. if i create an accessor like:
attr_accessor :name

it creates to methods:
name
and
name=

but when i call the second method with a whitespace between the 'name' and '=' it works

'n.name=' and 'n.name =' both works.

i read somewhere that Ruby ignores whitespaces. Well then, why a method written by me does not work when i call it with whitespace?

def getname
end

if i call this way, it doesn't work. why? 
t.get name

i'm not surprised as it does not work. but i'm confused how the setter method (name=) works then?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setters are special in Ruby.

> In fact, defining a method name ending in an equals sign makes that name eligible to appear on the left-hand side of an assignment.

from http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html

Assignments are defined in Ruby as:

> An assignment statement sets the variable or attribute on its left side (the lvalue) to refer to the value on the right (the rvalue).

from http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html

So `n.name=` is calling the setter `name=` directly.

`n.name =` is using this special treatment of setters by the fact that it ends in an `=`, to make it so that you can use it as the lvalue (that is, it can appear on the left side) in an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

getName is the name of the method, so you cannot have whitespace in that because then it thinks it is two methods or maybe a parameter, that is why we camal case to make it readable.  But the equal sign is an operand and there can be space around that.  Its the same as say '2+2' and '2 + 2'.
Hope that helps

Comment: but in setter, the = is the part of the method name. isn't it?

Comment: In Ruby, variable and method names should be in lower case and words should be separated by underscores. Use of camel case is strongly discouraged, except in class names.